RAG returning prompt + context + answer as output whereas i just need the answer
I'm trying to build a conversational RAG with chat history kept in memory. The output gives everything including the context, prompt template, question and answer. I just want the answer.
Code
   conversational_rag_chain = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
       rag_chain,
       get_session_history,
       input_messages_key="input",
       history_messages_key="chat_history",
       output_messages_key="answer",
   )
      print(query)
      result = conversational_rag_chain.invoke({"input": query},config={
        "configurable": {"session_id": "abc123"}
        })
      return result["answer"]

    if st.session_state.messages[-1]["role"] != "assistant":
                  with st.chat_message("assistant"):
                   with st.spinner("Loading"):
                   answer = qa(question)
                   st.write(answer)

                new_ai_message = {"role":"assistant","content": answer}
                st.session_state.messages.append(new_ai_message)


Output:

System: \n  [INST]\nAs an AI, provide accurate and relevant information based on the provided document. Your responses should adhere to the following guidelines:\n- Answer the question based on the provided documents.\n- Be direct and factual, summarize answers limited to 150 words and 5-6 sentences. Begin your response without using introductory phrases like yes, no etc.\n- Maintain an ethical and unbiased tone, avoiding harmful or offensive content.\n- If the document does not contain relevant information, state "I cannot provide an answer based on the provided document."\n- Avoid using confirmatory phrases like "Yes, you are correct" or any similar validation in your responses.\n- Do not fabricate information or include questions in your responses.\n- do not prompt to select answers. do not ask me questions\n[3] DennyBritz,AnnaGoldie,Minh-ThangLuong,andQuocV.Le. Massiveexplorationofneural\nmachinetranslationarchitectures. CoRR,abs/1703.03906,2017.\n[4] JianpengCheng,LiDong,andMirellaLapata. Longshort-termmemory-networksformachine\nreading. arXivpreprintarXiv:1601.06733,2016.\n10\n\nProvidedproperattributionisprovided,Googleherebygrantspermissionto\nreproducethetablesandfiguresinthispapersolelyforuseinjournalisticor\nscholarlyworks.\nAttention Is All You Need\nAshishVaswani∗ NoamShazeer∗ NikiParmar∗ JakobUszkoreit∗\nGoogleBrain GoogleBrain GoogleResearch GoogleResearch\navaswani@google.com noam@google.com nikip@google.com usz@google.com\nLlionJones∗ AidanN.Gomez∗ † ŁukaszKaiser∗\nGoogleResearch UniversityofToronto GoogleBrain\nllion@google.com aidan@cs.toronto.edu lukaszkaiser@google.com\n\nProceedingsoftheHumanLanguageTechnologyConferenceoftheNAACL,MainConference,\npages152–159.ACL,June2006.\n[27] AnkurParikh,OscarTäckström,DipanjanDas,andJakobUszkoreit. Adecomposableattention\nmodel. InEmpiricalMethodsinNaturalLanguageProcessing,2016.\n[28] RomainPaulus,CaimingXiong,andRichardSocher. Adeepreinforcedmodelforabstractive\nsummarization. arXivpreprintarXiv:1705.04304,2017.\n[29] Slav Petrov, Leon Barrett, Romain Thibaux, and Dan Klein. Learning accurate, compact,\n\ngnissim\ngnissim\n,\n,\nni\nni\nym\nym\nnoinipo\nnoinipo\n.\n.\n>SOE<\n>SOE<\n>dap<\n>dap<\nFigure4: Twoattentionheads,alsoinlayer5of6,apparentlyinvolvedinanaphoraresolution. Top:\nFullattentionsforhead5. Bottom: Isolatedattentionsfromjusttheword‘its’forattentionheads5\nand6. Notethattheattentionsareverysharpforthisword.\n14\n\n[/INST]\n\nHuman: name of paper?017/04/28..\n[4] The paper titled 'Massive Exploration of Neural Machine Translation Architectures' by authors Anna Goldie, Minh-Thang Luong, Quoc V Le, and Denny Britz explores a wide range of neural machine translation (NMT) architectures. It investigates various aspects such as different types of layers used in NMT models, attention mechanisms, and their impacts on translation quality.

I tried to use custom parsers using regex but the output is null

Can you share the complete code?
